# Match all identifiers in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

**Problem:**

I am looking for a way to match certain identifiers in a given line
   that starts with certain words. The ID consists of
   characters, possibly followed by digits, followed by a dash then some
   more digits. An ID should only be matched on lines where the
   starting word is one of the following: Closes, Fixes, Resolves. If a
   line contains more than one IDs, those will be separated by
   the string `and`. Any number of IDs can be present on a
   line.

**Example Test String:**

```
Closes PD-1                                           # Match: PD-1

Related to PD-2                                       # No match, line doesn't start with an allowed word

Closes                                                
NPD-1                                                 # No match, as the identifier is in a new line

Fixes PD-21 and PD-22                                 # Match: PD-21, PD-22

Closes PD-31, also PD-32 and PD-33                    # Match: PD-31 - the rest is not captured because of ", also"
Resolves PD4-41 and PD4-42 and PD4-43 and PD4-44      # Match: PD4-41, PD4-42, PD4-43, PD4-44

Resolves something related to N-2                     # No match, the identifier is not directly after 'Resolves'
```

**What I tried:**

Using a regular expressions to get all the matches, I always come up short in some regards. E.g. one of the regexp I tried is this:

`^(?:Closes|Fixes|Resolves) (\w+-\d+)(?:(?: and )(\w+-\d+))*`

1. I intended to have a non-capturing group where the line needs to
   start with one of the allowed words, followed by a single space:
   `^(?:Closes|Fixes|Resolves)`
2. Then at least one ID needs to follow the starting word,
   which I intend to capture: `(\w+-\d+)`
3. Finally, zero or more ID can follow the first one, which are
   separated by the string `and`, but I only want to capture the
   IDs here, not the separator: `(?:(?: and )(\w+-\d+))*`

Result of this regexp in python:

```py
test_string = """
Closes PD-1                                           # Match: PD-1
Related to PD-2                                       # No match, line doesn't start with an allowed word
Closes                                                
NPD-1                                                 # No match, as the identifier is in a new line
Fixes PD-21 and PD-22                                 # Match: PD-21, PD-22
Closes PD-31, also PD-32 and PD-33                    # Match: PD-31 - the rest is not captured because of ", also"
Resolves PD4-41 and PD4-42 and PD4-43 and PD4-44      # Match: PD4-41, PD4-42, PD4-43, PD4-44
Resolves something related to N-2                     # No match, the identifier is not directly after 'Resolves'
"""

ids = []

for match in re.findall("^(?:Closes|Fixes|Resolves) (\w+-\d+)(?:(?: and )(\w+-\d+))*", test_string, re.M):
    for group in match:
        if group:
            ids.append(group)

print(ids)
['PD-1', 'PD-21', 'PD-22', 'PD-31', 'PD4-41', 'PD4-44']
```

[Also, here is the result on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DQgLkW/1). If more than one ID follows the initial one, unfortunately it only captures the last match, not all of them. I read that a repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration, and I should put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations, but I couldn't make it work.

**Summary**:

Is there a solution for this with regular expressions, something similar to what I tried but which captures all the occurrences of the IDs? Or is there a better way to parse this string for the IDs, using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single capturing group and in that capturing group match the first occurrence and repeat the same pattern  0+ times preceded by a space followed by `and` and space.

The values are in group 1.

To get the separate values, split on  `and`

```
^(?:Closes|Fixes|Resolves) (\w+-\d+(?: and \w+-\d+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VOyhiD/1)

Comment: @Bence If you want get the matches in a capturing group you could make use of the pypi regex module https://pypi.org/project/regex/ using `(?:^(?:Closes|Fixes|Resolves)(?= \w+-\d+)|\G(?!^) (\w+-\d+)(?: and)?)` https://regex101.com/r/DeVNCZ/1

Comment: @Bence A python demo using the regex module https://rextester.com/VJESC20804

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier with the two-stage approach, such as:

```
def get_matches(test):  #assume test is a list of strings
    regex1 = re.compile(r'^(?:Closes|Fixes|Resolves) \w+-\d+')
    regex2 = re.compile(r'\w+-\d+')
    results = []
    for line in test:
        if regex1.search(line):
            results.extend(regex2.findall(line))
    return results
```

gives:

```
['PD-1','PD-21','PD-22','PD-31','PD-32', 
'PD-33','PD4-41','PD4-42','PD4-43','PD4-44']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to work with repeated capturing groups, you should install PyPi `regex` module with `pip install regex` and use

```
import regex

test_string = "your string here"
ids = []
for match in regex.finditer("^(?:Closes|Fixes|Resolves) (?P<id>\w+-\d+)(?:(?: and )(?P<id>\w+-\d+))*", test_string, regex.M):
    ids.extend(match.captures("id"))
print(ids)
# => ['PD-1', 'PD-21', 'PD-22', 'PD-31', 'PD4-41', 'PD4-42', 'PD4-43', 'PD4-44']
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/DDFAP9769)

The capture stack for each group is accessible via `match.captures(X)`.

The regex you have is fine to use as is, but it is more user-frienly with a named capturing group here.